# how the head pointer is still pointing to first element after travesing it in isert_at_end function?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define MAXSIZE 10 
int count=0; 

typedef struct list_node 
{ 
    int item; 
    struct list_node *next; 
}node; 
void insert_at_beginning(node **head_addr, int value) 
{ 
    if(count==MAXSIZE){ 
        printf("List can not accommodate more than 10 elements\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    }

    node *new_node; 
    new_node=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    new_node->item=value; 
    new_node->next= *head_addr; 
    *head_addr=new_node; 
    count++; 
}
void insert_at_end(node **head_addr, int value) 
{
    if(count==MAXSIZE) { 
        printf("List can not accommodate more than 10 elements\n"); 
        exit(0);
    }

    while(*head_addr != NULL){ 
        head_addr=&((*head_addr)->next); 
    }

    insert_at_beginning(head_addr,value); 
}

int main()
{
    node *head=NULL;
    insert_at_beginning(&head,1);
    insert_at_beginning(&head,0);
    insert_at_end(&head,2);
    return 0;
}
```

my question is after traversing in insert_at_end function when i use insert_at_beginning still it add at beginning  how can it done?
my code is working fine but i just wondering this thing.
i don't need to create any temp pointer to traverse

Comment: Please apply indentation.

Comment: Please explain why you are moving the head pointer itself to the end, if you want it to continue doing its job of poiting at the head. I.e. please explain why you do not create a temporary copy of it, and use that to do the inserting at the end.

Comment: @SourabhChoure Your edit will probably soon be accepted by others. But please consider whether you are really helping OP, if you do this for them (and nothing else as fas as I can tell, e.g. capitalisation, punctuation, readability...).

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer: because the pointer `head_addr` is only changed local to `insert_at_end()` so any changes made to that pointer itself in `insert_at_end ()` are lost on function return and the only pointer updated to a new address is the `->next` pointer of the last node when you call `insert_at_beginning (head_addr, value);`, e.g.

```
void insert_at_end (node **head_addr, int value)
{
    if (count == MAXSIZE) {
        printf ("List can not accommodate more than 10 elements\n");
        exit (0);
    }
    
    while (*head_addr != NULL) {
        head_addr = &((*head_addr)->next);
    }
    insert_at_beginning (head_addr, value);
}
```

Above `head_addr` is a pointer that is local to the function. Within `insert_at_end()` no new value is assigned to `*head_addr` it is only dereferenced to check whether the node is `NULL`. The local copy of `head_addr` is changed with `head_addr = &((*head_addr)->next);`, but that makes no change to what is contained at the address it holds as its value.

When you call `insert_at_beginning (head_addr, value);`, `head_addr` contains the address for the `->next` pointer of the last node in the list -- which is where your new node is being inserted. So in `insert_at_beginning()` where `*head_addr=new_node;` is finally dereferenced and assigned, you are updating the address held by the `->next` pointer of the last node from `NULL` to the new node you just allocated with `*head_addr=new_node;`

(this is a very appropriate use of the pointer)

You are iterating over the addresses of the nodes, not changing what is at each address. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: Thank you so much.I totally understand this your explanation is much better than our sir.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question -- please have the integrity to leave a comment why. This answer is 100% technically correct and answers the question -- on what basis are you downvoting?